# How can I increase the -XXMaxPermGen jvm settings in Jboss under MyEclipse?

Tags: java, jboss, myeclipse

When I start Jboss on My Eclipse, server is started with following vm arguments

INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Djboss.home=C:\JBoss -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\JBoss\lib\endorsed -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

When I insert a big persistence object, I am getting out of memory exceptions. Jboss should be started  **-Xms512M -Xmx1024M** .I have checked myeclipse ini file, I have change run.bat, run.conf.bat. I could not find where Myeclipse is reading this value.

Can you please show me the way to change jboss vm setting in MyEclipse 2014?

[image: This is MyEclipse]

When I select Manage Launch Configuration, this ui is shown

[image]

This is jboss definition in Run Configuration Panel

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please visit my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the memory settings for the JBoss server :

Go to Window > Preferences > MyEclipse > Servers > JBoss > expand JBoss x.x > JDK > Optional Java VM Arguments.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `Server` window
2. Double click on ths JBoss server
3. Under General Information, there is a link - Open Launch Configuration, click on it.
4. Window will open click on Arguments subtab.
5. Change VM arguments and Apply.
6. Restart Server.

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the below steps :**

**Option 1 :**

1) Open the server (double click on server)

2) Open launch Configuration

3) Go to argument tab

4) VM Arguments

and set your flag.

5) Restart Eclipse

For Graphical [view](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/setting-tomcat-heap-size-jvm-heap-eclipse/)

**Option - 2:**

1) Go to below path :

```
Window::Preferences::Java::Installed JREs::Edit::Default Vm Arguments:
```

2) Select variables button.

3) give any name suppose - vmargs

4) Edit variables

5) Select new button.

6) Add name name suppose vm (add the value size as per your requirement)

```
value : -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -XX:PermSize=2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

7) Select ok

8) Restart your eclipse.

Comment: I read this solution before. But double click does not work on MyEclipse

Comment: I am not sure but check the right click on server and find the configure option.